# How to change dynamically sortable placeholder and not to change draggable object over the sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

How not to change draggable object over the sortable?
How to change dynamically size sortable placeholder?

```
$(function() {
  $( ".block" ).draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    connectToSortable: ".sortable",
    helper: function () {
        return createContainer();
    }
  });
  $(".sortable").sortable({
    opacity: .35,
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    start: function(e,ui){
      ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
    },
    stop: function (e, t) {
      $(t.item).replaceWith(createContainer());
    }
  });
  //$( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
  var createContainer = function () {
    var el = $('<div class="block-new">replace</div>');
    return el;
};
});
```

[Fiddle](http://goo.gl/EK5soe)